# Was there something like "Entartete Wissenschaft" in Nazi Germany?

Tags: nazi-germany

It is welll known that there was something like "Entartete Kunst" in Nazi Germany. Degenerate art was all art of Jewish artists and art that didn't fit the nazi worldview.

Was all science conneted with jewishness also considered degenerate? Were there other forms of science that were considered degenerate (so not connected with jewishness)?

What was the attitude towards Einsteins general relativity? Did they really think this was "entarted"? Was jewish science in principle degenerate (though maybe used in the production of whatever, maybe even in the production of Zyclon B...)?

I think it is rather, eeeh, irrational, to put it in rather friendly words, to make the distinction, but then again the whole era was rather irrational, to put it mildly (and seen from our ratio).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there was definitely "Jewish science" in Nazi thought.

[Deutsche Physik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Physik) attempted to purge Jewish influence from science.  It was not entirely successful, in that while many Jews fled Germany and could not, of course, teach physics, they were unable to purge Heisenberg, a German but deeply involved in the physics they denounced.

Freud also came under attack for being Jewish, and [his books were burned](https://encyclopedia.ushmm.org/content/en/article/sigmund-freud).

Comment: Did they denounce quantum physics (Heisenberg)?

Comment: Yup.  Tried to purge him on the ground that not only Jews but Jewish thought had to go.

Comment: Was Schrödinger a Jew? Or any others involved. What if QM was invented by a Arian?